# Tkinter Text Resize

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my first time ever asking a question here, I've done my best to avoid it as much as I could up until this point, but I have reached a wall where I feel that I have explored all avenues for google searching and reading.

I am using tkinter library in python.  My goal is to have a window instantiate and refresh with new text every second.  The issue with my code is that the text (probably by default?) is extremely small.  I want the text to fit the window at all times.  Additionally, I want the text size to grow or shrink (still fitting) when the window is adjusted by the user.  This is my current tkinter code:

```
import tkinter as tk
try:
    import tkFont
except:
    from tkinter import font as tkFont


class display(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):    
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.font = tkFont.Font(size = 10)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, width=10, height=10)
        self.label.pack()
        self.update()


    def update(self):
        self.label.configure(font = self.font, text="I want some font right here")
        self.font = tkFont.Font(size = (-1 * round(self.winfo_height() - 100)))
        self.after(1000, self.update)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = display()
    root.mainloop()
```

I am probably already doing some funky things.  Any help is greatly appreciated. I will respond to any follow-up questions anyone may have.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/28883687/7432

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question refers to resizing fonts but I came across it looking for a way resize the Text widget. Perhaps this would be useful to someone. After reading through tcl docs I found that you can use expand and fill in the geometry manager like so:

```
somewidget.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
```

Apply the same to the parent and child if needed.