# Tkinter - relation between font type and width

Tags: python, tkinter

I apologize in advance if my question is a duplicate however I have not found an answer to this question.

I'm learning Tkinter and I'm struggling with understanding the relation between a label's font type, it's size and it's width and the length of the string in it.

Specifically, what my problem is:

- I have created a widget: a 800x640 canvas on which I want to place other
  widgets.
- On this canvas I want to place a label with some text which has the following
  attributes: font: Helvetica, font size: 20, text = "main application". I want
  to place this label widget at the very most top left corner of the
  widget(meaning at point 0,0 with respect to the canvas). I want the label to
  be 200 in width meaning it's background to take almost 1/3 of the canvas's
  size(after I manage to do this I plan to add 2 more labels as well). I guess
  the height of the label is determined by the font size in this case 20. I
  placed the label at coordinate y=20 and this coordinate seems to be ok.

I did some googling and found out that the width parameter of the label widget is not the actual width but something related to the font and size of the label's text: something like if I understood correctly: if the width is 6 than the label will be wide enough to contain 6 characters of, in my case verdana size 20. But I was not able to figure out what width and what x coordinate I should give my label so it starts at the x point of the canvas. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Menu

# Define the application class where we will implement our widgets
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        # CANVAS COLOUR DEFAULTS TO THE COLOUR OF THE WORKING WINDOW
        canvas = Canvas(master, width=800, height = 640, bg="gray") # IF YOU DO .PACK() HERE IT WILL RETURN NONE AND THEN YOU WILL HAVE PROBLEMS BECAUSE .PACK() RETURNS A 'NONE' TYPE OBJECT
        canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

        # The 'menu' of the application. The selection labels
        main_application_label = Label(master, text="main_application", font=("Helvetica", 20))
        main_application_window = canvas.create_window(103,20, window=main_application_label)

main_application = Tk()

main_application.title("main_application")

app = Application(main_application)

app_width = 800
app_height = 640

screen_width = main_application.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = main_application.winfo_screenheight()

x_coord = (screen_width/2) - (app_width/2)
y_coord = (screen_height/2) - (app_height/2)

main_application.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (app_width, app_height, x_coord, y_coord))
main_application.mainloop()
```

I have managed to somehow get the label at around point 0,0(by giving more values till I got it right) but the actual width of the label is not 200 pixels(~1/3 of the canvas). Please help me understand what values to the width parameter I should give so that my label's background is 1/3 of the canvas's size and if possible explain the relation between character font and width parameter so I can do that for any widgets regardless of their text's length. Thank you for reading my post!

Edit: What I wanted to do was to place 3 widgets(labels in this case but it doesn't matter) on the canvas. I did not understand what the 'anchor' option does and that was confusing me because I was expecting the center of the widget to be placed at the given coordinates all times but as I was changing anchor the placement of the center of the widget was changing and that was confusing me. It's all clear now thanks to @Bryan Oakley. Thanks.

Comment: Are you familar with [The Tkinter Menu Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm)

Comment: Have you tried to use the `width` option (in pixels) of `canvas.create_window`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TkInter Label Change Font Size by Text Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883687/tkinter-label-change-font-size-by-text-length)

Comment: By the way, putting labels on a canvas like that seems a bit over complicated to me, while you could either directly put text on the canvas with `create_text` or just grid or pack your labels above the canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the upper left corner of the text to be at (0,0), you don't have to adjust the coordinates based on the width. You can use the `anchor` option when creating the canvas object:

```
main_application_window = canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw",
                                               window=main_application_label)
```

If you really need to compute the actual size of the string, you can create a `Font` object and then use the `measure` method to find the actual width of a string in the given font.

```
from tkinter.font import Font
font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=20)
string_width = font.measure("main_application")
string_height = font.metrics("linespace")
```

This gives you the size of the rendered string. If you're using a label widget you'll also need to take into account the amount of padding and borders that the widget uses.

When you create items on a canvas, you can specify the width and height. For example, this makes the widget 200 pixels wide:

```
main_application_window = canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw", width=200,
                                               window=main_application_label, width=400)
```

Comment: This solved my problem. The anchor was what was confusing me. I did not fully understood it. I was under the impression that when you place a widget on the canvas you always place it's center at the x,y position. But you don't, you choose where the center gets placed with the anchor option. That is clear now thanks a lot. Sorry for the late reply I got cought in oder things and I did not have time to check this.

Comment: Bryan. I have created an Entry widget in which I only want to have space for 2 digits of a font of my choosing. Say ("Courier", 180). I have created such a Font then I have used font.measure("99") and obtained a width of 160 per character so I would need 320 width for 2 of them. However as you said the entry widget uses some internal padding so If I make a canvas window exactly 320 wide I will only be able to display one digit at a time in my entry the other goes out of the widget's display area to the left. Is there any way to specify 0 internal padding so my canvas window is as wide as "99"?