# Tkinter resize labels with grid_configure

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

I'm trying to have my labels, entry field, and buttons resize automatically if the window size is changed. I already figured out how to have a background image that resizes accordingly but cannot figure out how to use `grid_columnconfigure()` and `grid_rowconfigure()` to do it appropriately. I've tried using pack() to have everything arranged how I'd like but couldn't get it. I need to keep it to 3 columns overall. Also is there a way to center the title evenly? I've tried `columnspan` and `rowspan` but no dice there either. If you run this you'll need to insert an image into the "image" variable The code I'm using is:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = Tk()
window.title("Insert Window Title Here")
window.geometry('800x400')

def resize_image(event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image = photo)
    label.image = photo #avoid garbage collection

image = Image.open("/Users/useradmin/Tkinter_Projects/Untitled-1.png")
copy_of_image = image.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = ttk.Label(window, image = photo)
label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
label.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

title = Label(window, text = "Insert Title Here...", background = "black", foreground = "dark green", font = ("Times New Roman", 32), borderwidth = 2, relief = "solid")
title.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

question_1 = Label(window, text = "Insert Question Here?", background = "gray23", foreground = "dark green", font = ("Times New Roman", 20), borderwidth = 2, relief = "solid")
question_1.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
question_2 = Label(window, text = "Insert Question Here?", background = "gray23", foreground = "dark green", font = ("Times New Roman", 20), borderwidth = 2, relief = "solid")
question_2.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

entry_1 = Entry()
entry_1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
entry_2 = Entry()
entry_2.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

question_1_button = Button(window, text = "Insert Something Here")
question_1_button.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
question_2_button = Button(window, text = "Insert Something Here")
question_2_button.grid(column = 2, row = 2)
question_3_button = Button(window, text = "Insert Something Here")

window.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "resize"? Are you wanting the text to automatically grow and shrink, or simply that the widgets will expand or shrink to fill the window?

Comment: Well I would assume I need both the widgets and text within the widget to grow and shrink automatically

Comment: Here is a question specifically about resizing the text on a label. You can apply a similar approach to every widget that has text, if that is your goal. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28883687/7432