# Is there a way to detect wether text fits in a button/label and reduce font size until it fits while wraping the text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Disclaimer: re-uploaded question after someone closed it for being a duplicate while linking to a question which is very different. The question this was allegedly a duplicate of is [TkInter Label Change Font Size by Text Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883687/tkinter-label-change-font-size-by-text-length). The reason this question and its answer doesn't work in my case is that they are working with a single line of text and the solution only works on one line text since it works based on width. What I am asking is for a way to accomplish a similar result in regards to dynamically changing font size but because my UI is using text wrapping the "duplicate question" does not in fact answer my question since my text doesn't need to be scaled based on width but on total size / vertical size. The reason why scaling having single line text would not work is because my labels need to be able to hold entire sentences and/or paragraphs which would make the text unreadable small while leaving large amounts of empty space above and below the text.

To whoever closed my previous question please read and consider whether an existing question's answers would work or ask for more information rather than close the question for being similar in nature to an existing one.

I am currently using `myButton.bind('<Configure>', lambda _ : myButton.config(wraplength = myButton.winfo_width()-8,))` to wrap my text so it fits inside the button/label. This works great so long as everything fits in the window but if it doesn't it just pushes the text out the top and bottom of the window. In an effort to avoid this being a problem I am trying to find a way to dynamically reduce the font size in order to allow the text to fit. To make that work I am hoping there is a way for me to detect if the text fits in a label. The UI I am working on is dynamically scalable so when the window is too small it doesn't leave enough room for the text in some of the labels.

Update: I've found a way to get the number of lines being used post wrapping but still require a way to convert the number of lines to a number of pixels. How Can I get the line-height?

The method I used to get the number of lines is:

```
myText.count('1.0', 'end', 'displaylines')[0]
```

How can I get the number of pixels per line or total?

Comment: You can get the height of a line of text in a manner similar to how you get the width. The `measure` method of a font returns both height and width. You can then get the width and height of the button and compare.

Comment: How do I make .measure() return the height? when I use it in a print() function all it prints is the required width.