# How do I change the font of a dynamic text inside a widget with defined dimensions in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I am new to GUI and Tkinter in Python 3. My program intends to take a string from the user and display it in a **Message** Widget. However, due to the dynamic length of text, the dimensions of the widget(s) keep changing which results to change in the GUI structure of the root window (as according to the input text(string) size). I use the grid() system to position the widgets.

To preserve the structure so that the widgets do not change their dimensions (and hence, positions), How do I rather make the font size change so as the widget would enclose the entire text (string) but, keep the defined dimensions?

For example, I want my widget dimensions to be that of [image: this] and not like [image: this]  Download the images to see noticeable difference in the height and width. This change also makes other widgets shift changing the GUI structure (which I want to be the same for any length of text as input)

So, to compensate for the increased text length, I want the program to make the font size of the latter smaller, such that the dimensions of the widget remain that of former (the dimensions be fixed in the source code ).

An excerpt from the code for the shown widget is given below

```
import random
from tkinter import *
interface=Tk()
..
..

#here <abr> is the dynamic text given as input to the program as a string.
#here <abstract> is the widget (here,a Message widget) under consideration

color_codes=['#90eeed','#d681ff','#faf1ae','#57b1f4','#e5dcd4']
abstract = Message(interface,text=abr,font=('Century',15),aspect=350,bg=random.choice(color_codes),justify=CENTER)
abstract.grid(row=200,column=1)
abstract.update()
..
..
```

I don't want to add scrolling features in the root window. Any other alternative suggestions (which preserve the structure) would helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which illustrates the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/28883687/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley this answer deals with the pack() system, whereas I'm using the grid() system. Also, the coding method looks unfamiliar to me. Have a look at the updated question. Thanks

Comment: The fact that the solution uses `pack` instead of `grid` is irrelevant. The same technique works in either case.

Comment: @BryanOakley This solution is based for one-line texts working on `width` , However as shown in the photos in the updated question, I deal with paragraphs wrapped up in `Message` widgets which has both `height` and `width`

Answer (score 0):

there are some differences with the geometry managers. some are easier to "fix" others not. by and large they can also be combined. the grid method is, however, the worse choice for dynamic effects.

I take from your code that you are looking for something dynamic in terms of color changes? you can "dice" hex. Here is an example

```
from tkinter import *                                                                       # IMPORTS //////////////////
import random

root = Tk()                                                                                 # WINDOW ATTRIBUTES ////////
width = root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2.5
height = root.winfo_screenheight() / 3.5
root.geometry("400x400+%d+%d" % (width, height))
root.attributes("-transparent", "red")
root.overrideredirect(1)


def circular():                                                                             # LABEL // CANVAS OUTSIDE //
    global GLOBAL_STATE, EXTENT                                                             # FUNC()
    if GLOBAL_STATE == 0:
        main_canvas.itemconfig(outer_arc, extent=EXTENT, start=EXTENT,
                               fill="#"+("%06x"%random.randint(0,16777215)))
        main_label.configure(text="CPU-HEAT\n"+("%d"%random.randint(0,9999999)+"°C"),
                             fg="#"+("%06x"%random.randint(0,16777215)))
        exit_button.configure(fg="#"+("%06x"%random.randint(0,16777215)),
                              activeforeground="#"+("%06x"%random.randint(0,16777215)))
        main_canvas.after(10, circular)
        EXTENT += 3.6

def circular_in():                                                                          # CANVAS INSIDE FUNC() /////
    global GLOBAL_STATE, EXTENT_IN
    if GLOBAL_STATE == 0:
        main_canvas.itemconfig(inner_arc, extent=EXTENT_IN, start=EXTENT_IN,
                               fill="#"+("%06x"%random.randint(0,16777215)))
        main_canvas.itemconfig(oval_blink, fill="#"+("%06x"%random.randint(0,16777215)))
        main_canvas.after(15, circular_in)
        EXTENT_IN -= 3.6

GLOBAL_STATE = 0                                                                            # STATEMENTS // GLOBAL /////
EXTENT = 0
EXTENT_IN = 0

main_canvas = Canvas(root, bg="red", highlightthickness=0)                                      ##==> CREATE CANVAS
oval_blink = main_canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 390, 390)                                          ##==> OVAL BLINKING
oval_main = main_canvas.create_oval(15, 15, 385, 385, fill="#050707")                           ##==> OVAL CONTAINER
outer_arc = main_canvas.create_arc(22, 22, 378, 378, fill="red", start=90)                      ##==> CREATE ARC
oval_inner = main_canvas.create_oval(26, 26, 374, 374, fill="black")                            ##==> CREAT INNER LINE
oval_main = main_canvas.create_oval(40, 40, 360, 360, fill="#050707")                           ##==> OVAL CONTAINER
inner_arc = main_canvas.create_arc(60, 60, 340, 340, fill="red", start=90)                      ##==> CREATE ARC
oval_lblcon = main_canvas.create_oval(65, 65, 335, 335, fill="#080a0b")                         ##==> OVAL LBL CONT.

main_canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

main_label = Label(main_canvas, font=("Consolas", 30), bg="#080a0b")
main_label.place(x=105, y=145)

exit_button = Button(main_canvas, bg="#080a0b", text="\u26CC", bd=0, font=("Segoe UI", 22),     ##==> EXIT APP /////////
                     activebackground="#080a0b", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=175, y=80)


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                  # RUN APP //////////////////
    circular()
    circular_in()
    root.mainloop()
```