# Tkinter. Resize the font size to fit in the window via changing window size

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, tkinter, resize

I'm trying to create a function, which will change the button font size to fit button's text in the window. I tried to play with 'step' function, where i used 'pixel steps'. Like

```
if 100 < window_width <= 200: 
     button.config(font=('Arial', 10)
elif 200 < window_width <= 300:
     button.config(font=('Arial', 20)
```

But here is a problem. If you insert too long text into the button, it ll run out of the 'if' conditions (as long as text length in pixel grows exponentially relative to the size of the font. Of cource i I can try to choose the right font values to make the transitions in size as smooth as possible, but it ll be really unproductive, imho. Plus this method is extremely PC depended. I don't want to write aka 30 'if' conditions to cover monitor variations from full HD to 4k.

So, summing up all of the above, i need a method, which will cause font (optionally: smooth) resizing, depending on screen size, to fill all button's text in the windows borders.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883687/tkinter-label-change-font-size-by-text-length/28906292#28906292) deals with a label instead of a button, but the technique should be the same.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley. This method works, but extremely laggy in my case. (May be my laptop is too old for that. Btw, thank u again. I found the method how to solve the problem. I ll post the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everyone, who tried to answer. At the end i've found the solution. Thank's to ChatGPT, lmao. Here is the code with my correction. May be it ll be usefull for someone. That's not a perfect solution, but one of the best in my case, which doesn't cause too much lag, glithces and fit the text inside the window all the time.

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk
root = Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.minsize(width=screen_width // 3, height=screen_height // 3)

button = Button(root, text="myanimelist.net")
button.pack(expand=True)

font_size = 12


def resize_font(event=None):
    global font_size

    width = root.winfo_width()
    height = root.winfo_height()

    a = int(height / 2)
    buff = len(button["text"])
    b = int(width / (buff if buff >= 7 else 7))
    new_font_size = min(a, b)
    if new_font_size != font_size:
        font_size = new_font_size
        button.config(font=("Arial", font_size))


button.bind("<Configure>", resize_font)

root.mainloop()
```